# In TypeScript, is there a safe way to write axiosResult.data.attendeeResults.username

Tags: typescript, undefined

Unless something goes badly wrong, I expect that the JavaScript object I'm referencing like this:

```
axiosResult.data.attendeeResults.username
```

will have real data in it. That is, `data` is defined, `attendeeResults` is defined and `username` is defined. If any of them are not defined, I would like the entire express to just quietly return undefined with no errors.

How can I do this in TypeScript? Or even just EcmaScript 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recommendation to add the `?` operator to javascript to achieve the same use case as `axiosResult?.data?.attendeeResults?.username` so that the property is only read if the LHS is not undefined or null. It returns `undefined` otherwise

In typescript, from the docs, [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator] you could use `axiosResult!.data!.attendeeResults!.username` to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using the [non null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) [official doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/pull/445/files)

From official TypeScript release notes:

```js
function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
    validateEntity(e);
    let s = e!.name;  // Assert that e is non-null and access name
}
```

In your case, you can perform the check on `axiosResult.data`:

```js
axiosResult.data!.attendeeResults!.username
```